# Triangle and inverted triangle using CSS borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following image example using CSS borders. Is this possible? Also, is it possible for it to be responsive as well? I started a fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/markob83/46KAa/) I know I've seen this somewhere, but can't remember where.

[image]

Here is what I have so far -

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="sign-up col-sm-9">

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <h3>SIGN UP to get the latest updates on Security News</h3>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>

        </div>  <!-- /.sign-up -->          

        <div class="invert"></div>

            <div class="submit col-sm-3">

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">

            </div>

    </div> <!-- /.row -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS -

```
.sign-up {
  background: #002d56;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sign-up h3{
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sign-up:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 70px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 69px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 70px solid #002d56;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.invert {
  position:relative;
}

.invert:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 70px solid #cfab7a;
  border-bottom: 69px solid #cfab7a;
  border-left: 70px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 118px;
}

.submit {
  background: #cfab7a;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
}

.submit:before {

}

.submit input[type="submit"] {
  background: #cfab7a;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: I like this overview of CSS shapes by Chris Coyier, it also contains the triangle you're looking for. http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have tried to achieve what you wanted, please check this code and take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hc39/)

**Note:** ***It has to be achieved with two triangles since the CSS triangles are drawn using borders.***

HTML:

```
 <div class="rectangle"></div> 
 <div class="hidden-div">
     <div class="big-triangle"></div>
     <div class="triangle"></div> 
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 63px 0 63px 80px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
    position:absolute;
}
.big-triangle {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 80px 0 80px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-17px;
}
.rectangle {
    background-color:#007bff;
    width:300px;
    height:125px;
    position:absolute;
}
.hidden-div {
    width:300px;
    height:110px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
}
```